# Uncaught in Promise. Subscribe is not a function. Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, get, subscribe

I get this error when I run the code below:

Uncaught in Promise. Subscribe is not a function.

I have been able to successfully run this code using a different api that didn't require an api key, so it was run without the { headers : new...} params. just this.http.get(this.apiUrl).subscribe.

Anyone know whats causing this error?

```
 apiUrl = "https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl"

 apiKey = (my-api-key)


    getNFL() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          this.http.get(this.apiUrl, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set("JsonOdds-API-Key", this.apiKey)).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
        },   err => {
        console.log(err);
       });
    });
```

Comment: Have you made sure that your apiKey works with a curl get? e.g. `curl -X GET https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/ -H "JsonOdds-API-Key: yourapikey"`

Comment: There is a typo in your http.get, you are not closing the options property with a `}`.  `this.http.get(this.apiUrl, { headers: ... }).subscribe()`

Comment: @Llai good catch! that is the issue!